# Getting Async Storage as Null when trying to test the code

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, asynchronous, storage

Tried to search in stackoverflow and followed all the answers given but getting the same error

@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

```
To fix this issue try these steps:

  • Rebuild and restart the app.

  • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.

  • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.

  • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest

If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage/issues

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/lib/commonjs/AsyncStorage.native.ts:23:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/lib/commonjs/index.ts:1:1)
```

Test case is getting failed even after trying to link the async storage and tried to close the metro and run the app but getting the same error. please tell any other solutions when trying in android